# Weightlessness felt during roller coaster rides

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Can someone explain the physics behind to why we feel weightless during roller coaster rides
Please indicate how the forces act in a clothoid loop .

Answer (score 0):

If you have boarded an aeroplane or a lift or a fast car moving downwards you also felt the same.
the weightlessness is because of the free fall under gravity.
http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-2/Amusement-Park-Physics
for the information on clothoid loop.

Answer (score -2):

Weightlessness is felt when the net force is 1 G — for a moment the rider is effectively in free fall. While riding the roller coaster, the net force is equal to the force of gravity plus the centripetal force (the sum of all the radial forces). Since gravity always provides a 1 G downward force, this means that the centripetal force must be 0. Centripetal force is equal to $\frac{v^2}{r}$ (where v is the velocity and r is the radius of the circle). Therefore, the velocity must be 0. Indeed, this is the case at the top of the roller coaster—at the moment when the rider switches from moving upward (positive velocity) to moving downward (negative velocity), the velocity is 0. At the top of the circle, only the velocity in the vertical direction is relevant because it is in the direction of the centripetal force at that moment (since the radius is vertical).

In a clothoid loop, the same physics is in effect. At the top, the velocity is 0 and therefore centripetal force is 0, leaving only the 1 G downward force of gravity.